# How to add generated files to visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, protobuf-net

I have *.proto files which automatically translating to C# code before build event. 
How I can to add them to current project automatically? I tried

```xml
<Target Name="BeforeCompile">
   <ItemGroup>
       <Content Include="Proto\*.*" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

and other options, but it not works. It will be perfect if I can to do this using PowerShell.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=39

Comment: David, thx for link, but it working with VS2008 only.

Comment: Seems there is a workaround here: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=332